# Netty 'handshake' decoder, better way to tell the client to send data

Tags: java, netty

in my client->server application, the client will send an opcode which tells the server which service to initiate, however the design is a tad odd when it comes to update requests, when I receive the opcode, the client expects 8 (dummy) bytes to tell it to start sending update data.

Here is my handshake decoder:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer, List<Object> out) {
    if (!buffer.isReadable()) {
        return;
    }

    int id = buffer.readUnsignedByte();

    switch (id) {
    case HandshakeConstants.SERVICE_GAME:
        ctx.pipeline().addFirst("loginEncoder", new LoginEncoder());
        ctx.pipeline().addAfter("handshakeDecoder", "loginDecoder", new LoginDecoder());
        break;
    case HandshakeConstants.SERVICE_UPDATE:
        ctx.pipeline().addFirst("updateEncoder", new UpdateEncoder());
        ctx.pipeline().addBefore("handler", "updateDecoder", new UpdateDecoder());

        // XXX: Better way?
        ByteBuf buf = ctx.alloc().buffer(8).writeLong(0);
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buf);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid service id");
    }

    ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
    out.add(new HandshakeMessage(id));
}
```

As you can see in the code after I add the appropriate encoder and channel handler for the service to the pipeline, I must write the 8 bytes to tell the client to start sending update data; is there any (clean) way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution makes sense and I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I'm glad it makes sense to someone :P it just feels wrong to me, I don't know why. Thanks for the reassurance.